# Sorting NSArray by a 2nd Dimension - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

Historically this sort factory has been able to sort an array of Invoice Item objects by one dimension. The various sort dimensions are stored inside an enum "state" as a property of the SortItem object. Here is the working implementation.

```
+(NSArray *)SortInvoiceItems:(NSArray *)items forSort:(SortItem*)sortItem forSecondarySort:(SortItem*)secondarySortItem {
    NSArray * primary = [items sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        InvoiceItems *iiA = (InvoiceItems *)a;
        InvoiceItems *iiB = (InvoiceItems *)b;
        switch(sortItem.state) {
            case DateAscending:
            case DateDescending: {
                return (sortItem.state == DateAscending) ? [iiA.transactionDate compare:iiB.transactionDate] : [iiB.transactionDate compare:iiA.transactionDate];
            }
            case SumDescending:
            case SumAscending: {
                return (sortItem.state == SumAscending) ? [iiA.netInvoiceAmount compare:iiB.netInvoiceAmount] : [iiB.netInvoiceAmount compare:iiA.netInvoiceAmount];
            }
            case UnitPriceDescending:
            case UnitPriceAscending: {
                return (sortItem.state == UnitPriceAscending) ? [iiA.uomNetAmt compare:iiB.uomNetAmt] : [iiB.uomNetAmt compare:iiA.uomNetAmt];
            }
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }];

    return primary;
}
```

You'll notice I've added a secondarySort param to the method signature that is unused. My objective is to allow sorting by this secondary dimension, sorting Invoice Item objects that have the same value for the primary dimension by this secondary dimension.

So if two items had the same .transactionDate for example, those two items would additionally be sorted by a second dimension, like Unit Price Descending.

EDIT: I have it working below, is there a more succinct way to write this?

```
+(NSArray *)SortInvoiceItems:(NSArray *)items forSort:(SortItem*)sortItem forSecondarySort:(SortItem*)secondarySortItem {

    NSSortDescriptor *primaryDescriptor;
    NSSortDescriptor *secondaryDescriptor;

    switch(sortItem.state) {
        case DateAscending:
            primaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"transactionDate" ascending:YES];
            break;
        case DateDescending:
            primaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"transactionDate" ascending:NO];
            break;
        case SumAscending:
            primaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"netInvoiceAmount" ascending:YES];
            break;
        case SumDescending:
            primaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"netInvoiceAmount" ascending:NO];
            break;
        case UnitPriceAscending:
            primaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"uomNetAmt" ascending:YES];
            break;
        case UnitPriceDescending:
            primaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"uomNetAmt" ascending:NO];
            break;
        default: NSLog(@"invalid sort item");
    }

    switch(secondarySortItem.state) {
        case DateAscending:
            secondaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"transactionDate" ascending:YES];
            break;
        case DateDescending:
            secondaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"transactionDate" ascending:NO];
            break;
        case SumAscending:
            secondaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"netInvoiceAmount" ascending:YES];
            break;
        case SumDescending:
            secondaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"netInvoiceAmount" ascending:NO];
            break;
        case UnitPriceAscending:
            secondaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"uomNetAmt" ascending:YES];
            break;
        case UnitPriceDescending:
            secondaryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"uomNetAmt" ascending:NO];
            break;
        default: NSLog(@"invalid sort item");
    }

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[primaryDescriptor, secondaryDescriptor];
    return [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

SECOND EDIT: Refactored to this:

```
+(NSArray *)SortInvoiceItems:(NSArray *)items forPrimarySort:(SortItem*)primary forSecondarySort:(SortItem*)secondary {

    NSSortDescriptor *primaryDescriptor = [self GetDescriptorForSortItem:primary];
    NSSortDescriptor *secondaryDescriptor = [self GetDescriptorForSortItem:secondary];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[primaryDescriptor, secondaryDescriptor];

    return [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}

+(NSSortDescriptor *)GetDescriptorForSortItem:(SortItem*)sortItem {
    switch(sortItem.state) {
        case DateAscending:
            return [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kTransactionDateString ascending:YES];
        case DateDescending:
            return [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kTransactionDateString ascending:NO];
        case SumAscending:
            return [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kNetInvoiceAmount ascending:YES];
        case SumDescending:
            return [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kNetInvoiceAmount ascending:NO];
        case UnitPriceAscending:
            return [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kUOMNetAmount ascending:YES];
        case UnitPriceDescending:
            return [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kUOMNetAmount ascending:NO];
        default:
            return [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kTransactionDateString ascending:NO]; // default to date descending
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it's "difficult". Why is this not exactly the problem that NSSortDescriptor is intended to solve???

Comment: Didn't realize that, Matt. Thanks.

Wow, you literally wrote the book on the subject.

Comment: To condense it a bit more, swap that switch statement into a seperate method that can be called twice to return the descriptor based on a passed in state

Comment: What I would do is make the sort descriptor part of the SortItem state.

Comment: Yeah! Could be condensed even further, since the only thing that varies in your `return` statements is the key and the ascending bool. I can imagine a dictionary keyed by state...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSArray`'s `-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` to solve this problem. Using this method, you can provide an array of `NSSortDescriptor`s, the second of which will function as a secondary sort (and if there's a third one, it will be the tertiary sort, etc.).

You can create a `NSSortDescriptor` using `-[NSSortDescriptor initWithKey:ascending:comparator:]` and passing your comparator block.

Answer (score 0):

Construct the sort using an NSSortDescriptor, as explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html

**EDIT**:
In your case, since you have a SortItem property called `state` which determines the sort descriptor, and since it is in your power to construct that `state` type however you wish, I would suggest that you make the sort descriptor part of the state itself. That way, when it's time to sort, there is no work to do: the state itself supplies the sort descriptor that you will use, and you can get rid of the switch in `SortInvoiceItems`. In general, switches can be seen as a Bad Smell that suggests you have not devised your object types correctly; you should let the actual object know what to do rather than switching on something.

Comment: Even KVC is not necessary, since `NSSortDescriptor` can be initialized using a comparator block, like the one the OP already has in the question.